# How hackable is ActionScript Code

Tags: actionscript-3, networking

I'm working on a little networked flash game. I have my own server built in C/Linux and I connect to the server via a flash socket. I'm debating whether to put the heavy load of game logic on the client or on the server. The main concern is someone hacking the code and ruining the game for others.

Even if I put as much logic on the server as I can, if someone can hack the code and figure out my messages that are sent to the server it seems impossible to stop all intrusions.

How should I handle this and how worried should I be about AS3 hackers?

Comment: What is your metric for "hackability?"

Comment: You could at least obfuscate your code, there are several apps that do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gave a talk on a conference 2 years ago about protecting flash games. [Check out the slides](http://www.slideshare.net/flashgamm/valentin-simonov-who-cracks-our-games-and-how-that-is-done).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is pretty easy to decompile a swf and modify it as desired. The risk is fairly low, but if there is some large possible monetary reward, then yes I would be careful.

So, my advice is:

- Don't put high risk logic on the client
- But do put high cost algorithms on the client.

---

**Edit**: I would like to add one more point. If the server is relying on the client to it some state of the game, you can also proxy, inspect, and then modify the requests with a tool like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/). Someone can use this tool to setup breakpoints on requests, and then modify the results before forwarding them to the server. It is even easier than decompiling and modifying a swf.

The lesson is, you should never rely on having an honest client.

Comment: Thanks guys. But even if I put all of my logic on the server all someone would have to do is find the messages that my client sends to the server and they could cause havoc. I don't know any way to avoid that, do you?

Comment: yes never ever trust the client always assume the client app is trying to cheat. Verify all packets. Since it is a game the client should be "dumb" anyhow. No game logic on the client. Mirroring some logic for the purposes of prediction is fine but make sure the server is the one in charge.

Comment: This is one of the greatest answers so far. I have seen a fully executable to project decompilers lately of C#, Java, and Delphi code, but this doesn't means we shall stop writing an applications. Just follow the best anti hack practices, and everything shall be fine. After all a compiles file which is hard to be pached on fly is much better than fully applications source ( html-js projects ) which can be even debuged on the fly - isnt it :)

Answer (score 0):

Flash code is incredibly easy to hack. I may be wrong, but I think that when you decompile a swf, it's a full decompile - it gives you the original names of the variables and everything. It's also fairly easy to use tools like Cheat Engine to modify memory while the game is running. Unless you intentionally obfuscate your code and your data structures, I'd recommend putting most computation on the server.

Comment: Basically every code can be hacked, but this doesnt means it is easy to be pached on the fly.